# Uniqueness of solution to abstract wave equation with unsigned energy

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces, wave-equation

Let $H$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $(\mathcal{H}, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$). Suppose the spectrum of $H$ in $(-\infty, 0)$ consists of only finitely many eigenvalues $\mu^2_k < 0$, with corresponding normalized eigenfunctions $v_k$ (for definiteness, let's say $\text{Im}\, \mu_k > 0$). Concretely, the example I am thinking of is $\mathcal{H} = L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $V \in L^\infty_{\text{comp}}(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{R})$,  and $H = -\partial^2_x + V(x)$ (with domain the Sobolev space $H^2(\mathbb{R})$). In this specific situation, all of the eigenspaces corresponding to the $\mu_k$ will have dimenson one, and we can assume without of generality the eigenfunctions $v_k$ are real-valued.

Given some initial conditions $w_0 \in H^2(\mathbb{R})$, and $w_1 \in H^1(\mathbb{R})$, we can write down a solution $w(t) \in C^2((0,\infty); L^2(\mathbb{R}))$, $w(t) \in D(H)$ for all $t > 0$, to the abstract initial value problem:
$$\begin{cases} (\partial_t^2 + H)w(t) = 0 \\ w(0) = w_0, \, \partial_tw(0) = w_1 \end{cases}, $$
namely
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
w(t) &= \mathbf{1}_{\ge 0}(H)\Big[\cos(t|H|^{1/2})w_0 + \frac{\sin(t|H|^{1/2})}{|H|^{1/2}}\Big] \\  
&+ \sum_k \Big[\cos(t\mu_k)\langle v_k, w_0 \rangle + \frac{\sin(t \mu_k)}{\mu_k} \langle v_k, w_1 \rangle  \Big]v_k.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

> My question is: Is this the **unique** solution $w(t)$ in $C^2((0,\infty), \mathcal{H})$ to the initial value problem that satisfies $w(t) \in H^2(\mathbb{R})$ for all $t > 0$?

When $H$ has no spectrum in $(-\infty, 0)$, uniqueness of the initial value problem stated above can be proved by showing that the energy

$$E[w](t) = \frac{1}{2} \big[\| \partial_t w(t) \|^2 + \| |H|^{1/2}w(t)\|^2 \big] \ge 0$$

is a conserved quantity. However, the calculation I am familiar with relies on $H = |H|$.

If we possibly have some spectrum in $(-\infty, 0)$, here is a more general way to define define the energy (consistent with previous case when $H \ge 0$):
$$E[w](t) = \frac{1}{2} \big[\| \partial_t w(t) \|^2 + \langle w(t), H w(t) \rangle \big],$$
Once again and short calculation shows this energy is conserved. However, in this more general setting, since $E[w](t)$ is unsigned, it's conservation may not grant uniqueness of solutions.

Is there another method to establish uniqueness of solutions? Or is there something more flexible about the energy method that I'm not perceiving?

Comment: You didn't say what notion of solution exactly you're considering, but the answer must be yes, by the spectral theorem if you view the equation $u''+Hu=0$ as an ordinary differential equation in $L^2$ (space variables). In that case, the general solution is a linear combination of $\cos t\sqrt{H} u$, $\sin t\sqrt{H}/\sqrt{H} v$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, though I think there may be an issue because I did not specify that $H$ is nonnegative. But in any case, now I see how to proceed. If you project the solution onto one of the negative eigenspaces, you reduce to a second order ODE with constant coefficients, and we have existence and uniqueness for the initial value problem in that case. Thanks!

Comment: You do not in fact need any assumptions on $H$ other than self-adjointness for the Hilbert space valued equation to have unique solutions.